# Getting HTML table code in the Excel sheet while export in PHP

Tags: php, html, excel

I am exporting the data in PHP but I am getting a table source in the Excel sheet.

Check below image:

[image]

How can I investigate this issue?

HTML

```
 <form action="export.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="action" value="exportSubscribe"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-light-green" value="Export"></form>
```

Export.php

```
function exportSubscribe($pdo){
$sql = "SELECT `s_id`,`s_name`, `s_emailphone`,`pagename`,date_of_created FROM `tbl_subscribe` WHERE is_active=1";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
// $stmt->bindParam('is_active', 1);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$output = '';
$output .= '
   <table class="table" bordered="1"> 
         <tr>  
          <th>Name</th>  
          <th>Email/Mobile no</th>  
          <th>Pagename</th>  
          <th>Date of created</th>
         </tr>';

foreach ($result as $row) {
    $output .= '
            <tr>  
               <td>'.$row["s_name"].'</td>  
               <td>'.$row["s_emailphone"].'</td>   
               <td>'.$row["pagename"].'</td>  
               <td>'.$row["date_of_created"].'</td>
              </tr>';         
}
$output .= '</table>';
  header('Content-Type: application/xls');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.xls');
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
  header("Expires: 0");
  echo $output;
}
```

Comment: or you could create a csv file too. microsoft office can open it too

Comment: @Kevin, How can I create the CSV file? I just change the extention from xls to csv and I got the same issue.

Comment: @user9437856 csv means comma separated value.  In this format you separate each field with a comma (or other delimiter). Just changing the extension will not work. You need to output in csv. Other option is to use xml. This is the format used in xlsx and can be read by Excel

Comment: @smartdroid, I need to know what code I have to change it for CSV?

Comment: @Kevin, I tried the CSV but getting some issues. I updated the code. Please check it once